# Submit buttons in Zurb: do you use an <a> or?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm not really getting the rationale behind the overabundance of `<a>`s in the code at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html; and the lack of representation for the other elements.

Short of **one** mention, and one line, both under the `Accessibility` section, no mention is made of any other element (why not `<button>`, or `<input>` for example?). It almost seems as if (due to the overwhelming overrepresentation) the documentation were saying "we really designed this for `<a>`s". Is that really the case?

(Small aside: the line that mentions using other elements, I have a problem with: `If there is no <a href=""> then simply add the tabindex="0" to the div or span to make it focusable.` If a button is focusable, I expect to be able to trigger it with the spacebar. Unfortunately, when you've got a div or a span, you can't. So is this really useful, or even constructive?)

I get that you can use `<a>`s for cases where no forms are involved, but what of your standard "submit" button where a form is involved? Wouldn't using a `<button>` resolve all the issues that you would have using an `<a>`? 1. It's focusable. 2. When focussed, you can trigger it with the spacebar. 3. You can conveniently press `<Enter>` to submit the form. What do other folks use for your submit button/s?

Comment: Even the examples [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html) all use `<a>` elements for buttons. I don't know much about Foundation, but this has me questioning why it exists at all.

Comment: well now, it's never crossed my mind, but you're right! The examples there look like they could be AJAX actions, rather than actual form submissions, but either way, it only goes to show that some thought has to go into the documentation....

Answer (score 0):

The buttons tags are usable in foundation 5. There is not a lot of documentation on it but (and I tested it to make sure I was correct) the `<button>` tag works as normal.

The `<a>` tag is used on the example site sure, but that doesn't limit its use when working with it.

You should still use `<button>` with forms and use `<a>` for links.

If you look at adioso.com (they use foundation) and inspect their forms, they use buttons for functional uses outside of links.

```
<form class="flight_search" method="get" action="/search_form">
   <div class="search_form_inputs">
      <ul class="row">
         <li class="columns large-3 small-12 medium-6">
         <li class="columns large-3 small-12 medium-6">
         <li class="columns large-3 small-12 medium-6">
         <li class="columns large-3 small-12 medium-6">
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="search_sundries">
      <div id="passengers" class="awesome-search">
         <div id="submit-wrap">
            ###<button id="submit-btn" type="submit" class="search_button" tabindex="9">Find Flights</button>###
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Check the above code. The example website isn't a very solid representation of what foundation can do but play with it a bit and you'll see its a very solid framework.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware and am using <button>s right now, but thought to ask fellow users what they're doing with Foundation. Your point about looking to a reference site was helpful; but I would have more assurance looking to an actual showcase site than some other site that I'm not familiar with (see http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/website-examples.html)

Comment: @Jeffrey 'jf' Lim: Hmm that sounds like your question may be off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions seeking anecdotal uses don't quite fit the format because there is no one objectively best answer. This answer looks like it's trying to keep things on-topic by providing factual references.

Comment: It's anecdotal in one sense, but also at the same time fact-checking. I just couldn't quite believe what I was seeing in the documentation.

Comment: I do agree the document site isn't a very good example and finding other sites that use foundation maybe a few steps harder than an official site, its is the only answer I can think to give. I hope it helped at little bit. I guess its a matter of opinion but I would think most people who are using a framework like foundation would know where to use buttons or the anchor links. That is purely an assumption. I suppose you'd just go about using the same codes as a normal HTML5 document. Sorry if this is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Got it, and I appreciate the effort, Joey. My only concern was taking reference from a site that I'm not sure I can hold up as a good example of what to do. Are you sure you have the name of the site correct, btw? The site redirects to another domain that sounds and looks almost like it's into domain name squatting.

Comment: I apologize I had a typo on the web address. It should be www.adioso.com. My computer autocorrected it. I edited my first reply to match.

I do agree the example from the main site is not too solid.

Comment: Thanks, Joey for the correction. Glad it was just a typo! That site had me wondering for a while... :)